# Array of Union-type of Class.class and Struct.class

Tags: crystal-lang

I'm trying to get a list of classes of other classes and structs.
I currently have the following code (reduced to minimum)

```
struct Foo
end

class Bar
end

alias Baz = Foo.class | Bar.class

types = [
  Foo, Bar, Foo, Foo, Bar, Baz
] of Baz
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Error in ./test.cr:9: instantiating 'Array(Bar:Class | Foo:Class):Class#build(Int32)'

types = [
        ^

in ./test.cr:9: instantiating 'Array(Bar:Class | Foo:Class):Class#build(Int32)'

types = [
        ^

in ./test.cr:9: no overload matches 'Pointer(Bar:Class | Foo:Class)#[]=' with types Int32, (Bar:Class | Foo:Class):Class
Overloads are:
 - Pointer(T)#[]=(offset, value : T)

types = [
        ^
```

I need this to perform type-checking on values generated at runtime and of an unknown type. The types inside the array are known at compile-time. The types against which I need to compare them are not. Small example (pseudocode)

```
types = [TString, TFunc] # struct, class
arg_0 = arguments[i]
arg_type = types[i]
if arg_0.is_a? arg_type
  # passed
else
  # failed
end
```

This code is being generated in a macro. Is this possible? Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are putting Baz inside the array, which is neither Foo nor Bar, it's a union type class. If you remove Baz from the array then it works fine.

Comment: How would I got about it, if I wanted to put Baz inside the array as well?

Comment: But why do you want to do that? We might be running into the XY problem where you want to do something without explaining the real problem you are trying to solve. Probably `of Foo.class | Bar.class | Baz.class` should work.

Comment: I basically had a macro that would receive an array of TypeDeclarations (similar to record). Then I would compare these types against an array that would be filled at runtime. This array would contain instances of said classes. It's part of a small DSL.

At the end I found a way to solve this entirely differently. Thanks for your answer.